# Displaying empty rows by Telerik RadGrid while viewing page in browser

Tags: asp.net

I added Telerik RadGrid in an ASP.Net project, i want while browsing the page to display multiple empty rows and i want to add data direct to the grid either text or drop down or checkbox columns. I don't want to connect to datasource just empty rows. If cannot be through RadGrid what i can use else.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want are empty rows, create any object that you can iterate over, like a collection, and throw that object into the datasource of the grid. Below is a very basic example.

Example:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" runat="server">  
</telerik:RadGrid>

protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Some Column", typeof(string));

    table.Rows.Add(""); // Add some empty rows
    table.Rows.Add("");
    table.Rows.Add("");

    RadGrid1.DataSource = table; 
}
```